# Previewing multiple image and videos in Single Activity

Tags: android, video, imageview, android-videoview

I am trying to display two ImageView in single actvity.These Imageviews consist of frame of video.When they are clicked there corresponding video start playing.But The problem is when I capture first video and return to main actvity no image is displayed.When I capture second video and return to main actvity image preview of first video is displayed.And when I click on it just black screen is displayed, When I was using single VideoView and single ImageView for single video it was working fine. I am using fileUri and fileUri1 to store the path of videos. Is there problem in Layout or some programming error or positioning of views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Capture picture button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCapturePicture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Take a Picture"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <!-- Record video button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRecordVideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Record a Video"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/See"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="See Video" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Preview"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <!-- To display picture taken -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgPreview2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- To preview video recorded -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/videoPreview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/videoView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    // directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

    public static Uri fileUri=null;
    public static Uri fileUri1=null;// file url to store image/video

    private ImageView imgPreview,imgPreview2;
    private VideoView videoPreview,videoPreview2;
    private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo,btnSee;
    private int countClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        imgPreview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview2);
        videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
        videoPreview2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);

        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);
        btnSee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.See);


        countClick=0;
        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                countClick++;
                recordVideo();
            }
        });
        btnSee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // capture picture

                Intent i= new Intent();

                //Uri uri = i.getParcelableExtra("fileUri");
                i.putExtra ("fileuri",fileUri);
                //i.putExtra ("fileuri1",fileUri1);
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }



    /*
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
        //outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
        //fileUri1 = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri1");
    }

    /*
     * Recording video
     */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if(countClick%2==0){
            fileUri1 = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);



            // set video quality
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri1); // set the image file
            // name
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 20);
            // start the video capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
        }else{
            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

            // set video quality
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
            // name
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 20);
            // start the video capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);



        }

    }




    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }



    /*
     * Previewing recorded video
     */
    private void previewVideo() {
        try {
            // hide image preview
            //if(fileUri==null)
            //{
            /*imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
            // start playing
            videoPreview.start();*/
            /*videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Bitmap bmThumbnail;
            bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(fileUri.getPath() , 
                       Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);*/
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            videoPreview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //both videoviews are made invisible and both imageviews are made visible

            if(countClick>=2){
                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgPreview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                MediaMetadataRetriever retriever1 = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                retriever.setDataSource(fileUri.getPath());
                retriever1.setDataSource(fileUri1.getPath());
                Bitmap myBitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(1000000);
                Bitmap myBitmap1 = retriever1.getFrameAtTime(1000000);
                imgPreview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                imgPreview2.setImageBitmap(myBitmap1);
            }else{
                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                retriever.setDataSource(fileUri.getPath());
                Bitmap myBitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(1000000);
                imgPreview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }



            imgPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //clicking on first imageView

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imgPreview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //first videoview video starts playing
                    videoPreview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());

                    videoPreview.start();

                }


            });
            imgPreview2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //clicking on secong imageview

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    imgPreview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    videoPreview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //second videoview video starts playing
                    videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    videoPreview2.setVideoPath(fileUri1.getPath());

                    videoPreview2.start();
                }


            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
     * */

    /*
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /*
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        /*if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else*/ if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: still problem..when first video is recorded no preview is displayed..when second video is recorded image preview of first video is displayed..when i click on image preview a black screen is displayed.thereafter if i record any number of videoes image preview of first video is displayed only..This time iamge preview was of small size and at different position..thts fine but the same problem is still there

Comment: i got one mistake..inside imgPreview2.setOnClickListener() its should be videoPreview2.start(); instead of videoPreview.start(); but there is some other problem also..

Comment: Also it should be  Bitmap myBitmap1 = retriever1.getFrameAtTime(1000000); instead of Bitmap myBitmap = retriever1.getFrameAtTime(1000000);  but there is some other problem also

Comment: can you please let me know what kind of problem have you getting?

Comment: i'll check again and let you know in 2 minutes

Comment: When i record first video no image preview and no video preview is displayed.thereafter i record any video it works fine as image preview is displayed and when i click on that image preview video preview is displayed..the problem is only that for first video i record no preview is displayed on main activity

Comment: can you please send your project on mail show i will check what is exactly going on there ?

Comment: That means i thing ImageView imgPreview not showing Image Preview

Comment: one more error found..it should be.. imgPreview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview2);   but still some problem which i record first video no preview is displayed and when i record second video it works fine as both image previews are displayed and when i click on them there corresponding video previews are displayed..only problem is displaying preview when first video recorded

Comment: i have edited my ans so you can just replace this code.

Comment: Thanks a lott..its working fine..just want to know if u can tell me if I want to increase the size of video preview what changes should I make in Layout..what change should I make to android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     and android:layout_height="match_parent" as it is showing very small size video

Comment: try to change width as android:layout_width="match_parent"